# Animation Action

Tags: animation, .fbx, actions

I'm new to Blender so probably I'm asking a stupid question.

When I export an FBX with some Actions baked in, I found in the baked file a lot more Action than what I expect. It seems like the original action has been applied separately to each object that was part of the animated group (Parented objects) and baked consequently.

Can someone help me to find the correct way to bake a file of for example a drawer with all is in it with an action for the opening and another for the closure?

Answer (score 1):

Open **NLA Editor** and add all necessary actions here:

[image]

In FBX export settings, uncheck **All actions** and check **NLA Strips**:

[image]

This will export only actions added in NLA editor

Comment: Thank you Crantisz for your help; i'm gong to try it immediately.